# for a long time / for a while

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage

Can I say "I haven't written to you **for a long time**" instead of "**for a while**"? And what exactly does "for a while" mean in that phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"While"** (noun) - means *a period of time*. Examples:

- "We chatted for a while."
- "They didn't see each other for a while."

> Another good question to ask ourselves is: How long is "a while"?
>
> - *"You'll have to wait a while"* usually means *"You'll have to wait a long time."* However the time value differs according to context; it can be "a minute", "an hour", "a day", "a week" and e.t.c.
>
> *"Quite"* often modifies *"while"* and often means *"for a long time"*:
>
> - I haven't seen him for quite a while.
>
> *"Short"* and *"long"* can also modify *"while"*:
>
> - It's been a short while since I've heard from him.
> - He has been sitting here for a long while.

**"Long time"** - means *a long period of time*. Examples:

- "I haven't seen you for a long time."
- "It takes him a long time to come here."

**Note:** you can use **"long"** as a noun to imply the same meaning:

- *I haven't seen you for long* = *I haven't seen you for a long time*

Depending on what you wish you say you can use either!

Comment: That's what I wanted to know about "for a while". Thank you!